# Can't setup react native firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-firebase

I have a react native project and I want to use react native firebase,
I just follow all the [installation Docs](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/installation/ios#2.-React-Native-Firebase-Installation-Recommended-installation) to set up it in IOS, 
but in every time I build the project I got this error

> 'RNFirebaseUtil.h' file not found

in this path

> /Volumes/App/node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/functions/RNFirebaseFunctions.m

*in XCode*

[image: Path]

So how can I solve this issue?

```
 "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "^8.1.0",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.0.1",
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-native": "0.59.8",
    "react-native-firebase": "5.3.1",
  }
```

Podfile

```
# Uncomment the next line to define a global platform for your project
# platform :ios, '9.0'

target 'App' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for App
    pod 'RNFirebase', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios'

# Required by RNFirebase
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '~> 6.5.0'

# # [OPTIONAL PODS] - comment out pods for firebase products you won't be using.

  pod 'Firebase/Auth', '~> 6.5.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Database', '~> 6.5.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Functions', '~> 6.5.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Storage', '~> 6.5.0'


  target 'AppTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

end

target 'App-tvOS' do
  # Comment the next line if you don't want to use dynamic frameworks
  use_frameworks!

  # Pods for App-tvOS

  target 'App-tvOSTests' do
    inherit! :search_paths
    # Pods for testing
  end

post_install do |installer|
  rnfirebase = installer.pods_project.targets.find { |target| target.name == 'RNFirebase' }
  rnfirebase.build_configurations.each do |config|
    config.build_settings['HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS'] = '$(inherited) Pods/Headers/Public/**'
  end
end

end
```

Comment: do you run pod install ?

Comment: @Maleking yeah sure

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me was,

- 1.running npm uninstall on all the firebase packages and then reinstalling them
- 2.running 'pod update' in the ios folder,
- 3. cleaning the xcode build folder by holding down command + option + shift + k,
- 4. build project again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have some version mismatch. If you are using react-native-firebase 5.3.1 (from package.json) then you should look here for the ios SDK version:

https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/releases/v5.3.x#iOS---Update-Firebase-SDKs

Also there is a mismatch with 5.3.1 rnf and .59.8 rn. You should be using 5.5.x rnf for that rn version. See Here:

https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/getting-started#Supported-versions---React-Native-/-Firebase

Make sure to also upgrade your SDK also if you are upgrading react-native-firebase from 5.3.x to 5.5.x. So you would then update your pod via here:

https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/releases/v5.5.x#iOS---Update-Firebase-SDKs

Comment: thanks, @ageoff, I update the podfile with these versions, but the issue is still sadly!

Comment: My guess now is the RN and react-native-firebase library mismatch. If you are on .59.8 for RN then you should be using 5.5.x firebase and not 5.3.x. See here: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/getting-started#Supported-versions---React-Native-/-Firebase

Comment: @OliverD I updated my answer with some more details on the version mismatches. I would also recommend to remove your pods directly to completely clean it out between Podfile changes if you don't do that already.

Comment: i'm do all of these :( but i have got new issue 
 Path > node_modules/react-native-firebase/ios/RNFirebase/perf/RNFirebasePerformance.h
Error
'`React/RCTBridgeModule.h' file not found`