# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "GTMSessionFetcher/Core"

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, google-tag-manager, gtmsessionfetcher

I am making a React-Native mobile application and want to incorporate Firebase and Firebase Authentication. However, I am facing this error when I run 'pod install' or 'pod update':

[image]

I did some research and found out that this issue has not yet been resolved by Google (https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/254418199), but I came across a workaround (https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/issues/10359) which said to add a version specifier to the Podfile: pod 'FirebaseAuth', '>= 9.6.0'. However, even after I added the line into the Podfile in my iOS folder, the same error still persists. May I know if I'm doing something wrongly?

Answer (score 30):

I stumbled upon the same issue. It seems it's a compatibility issue with the latest Firesbase SDK version (10).

For now something that worked for me is to place this at the top of the Podfile:

`$FirebaseSDKVersion = '9.6.0'` ([Docs](https://rnfirebase.io/#ios))

This overrides the default firebase sdk and assures it uses the downgraded version.

Now just execute `pod install` and give a try. If it doesn't work try removing the Podfile.lock and the Pods folder and try again.

BTW I didn't need this line in the Podfile as one of the resources you shared mentioned:

> pod 'FirebaseAuth', '>= 9.6.0'

Comment: Thank you, it works! :) But now my build fails when I run on the iOS simulator: The following build commands failed:CompileC Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Chatbot-eeojnmlkiuetmccwazfgajbalxbi/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/RNFBFirestore.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RNFBFirestoreCollectionModule.o /Users/xxx/Chatbot/node_modules/@react-native-firebase/firestore/ios/RNFBFirestore/RNFBFirestoreCollectionModule.m normal arm64 objective-c com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler (in target 'RNFBFirestore' from project 'Pods')
(1 failure) Any tips?

Comment: I also got a similar error (although I'm not quite sure if it's the same).

I solved it following this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62981498/5627152

Surprisingly uninstalling all my firebase dependencies and then installing them again worked like a charm. Give a try! I hope this also works for you.

Comment: I am currently using "@react-native-firebase/app": "17.0.0", for this also should i add $FirebaseSDKVersion = '9.6.0' in pod file ? what does this mean actually ?

Comment: @Sadanand "@react-native-firebase/app": "17.0.0" is what you have in your package.json. That's your npm package version. Behind the scenes a native package is installed which is FirebaseSDK (and the version differs from the the one in npm). The thing is that if you don't specify a version in your podfile then it will install the latest version (10.X.X) which is the one that has the compatibility issues.

In order for you to avoid those compatiblity issues you need to specify $FirebaseSDKVersion = '9.6.0' in the podfile which is a version that doesn't have this issue.

Comment: Worked like a charm with $FirebaseSDKVersion = '9.6.0'.
Using "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^17.3.1" and "@react-native-google-signin/google-signin": "^9.0.2" in package.json. 
I also tried using $FirebaseSDKVersion = '10.5.0' but did not work.

Answer (score 4):

try to delete Podfile.lock and run `cd ios && pod install --repo-update`

Answer (score 1):

What helped me is to add this into my pod file.

```
pod 'GTMSessionFetcher', :modular_headers => true
```

and then run

```
arch -x86_64 pod update GTMSessionFetcher/Core
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using the Unity game engine and had encountered the same issue with my iOS build. However, I managed to solve it by identifying a common dependency version of GTMSessionFetcher/Core. Initially, I had to downgrade to Firebase 9.6.0 because there was no common dependency with Firebase version 10 and GoogleSignIn 4.0.2.

Here's the revised pod file:

```
source 'https://cdn.cocoapods.org/'
platform :ios, '11.0'

target 'UnityFramework' do
  pod 'Firebase/Auth', '9.6.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Core', '9.6.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Firestore', '9.6.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Functions', '9.6.0'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging', '9.6.0'
  pod 'FirebaseInstallations'
  pod 'GoogleSignIn', '4.0.2'
  pod 'GTMSessionFetcher/Core', '1.7'
end
target 'Unity-iPhone' do
end
use_frameworks! :linkage => :static
```

The critical line in this pod file is:

```
pod 'GTMSessionFetcher/Core', '1.7'
```

I've chosen the exact common version for all of them. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

For me helped defining a specific version for GTMSessionFetcher, for example:

```
pod 'GTMSessionFetcher', '~> 2.1'
```

Check the message error for the requirements in your case, is asking for:

```
GTMSessionFetcher (~> 1.1) and GTMSessionFetcher (~> 2.1)
```

And probably in the Podfile.lock latest version breaks one of this requirements, so specifying an exact version in the Podfile that complies with the requirements, will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
 pod update GTMSessionFetcher/Core
```

Running pod update updates all pods in your project to the latest versions that are compatible with the version constraints specified in your Podfile. This can sometimes resolve compatibility issues and update dependencies to versions that work better together.